# Jest tests run in bash, but generate ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I am trying a very simple test in VSCode which I am trying to ensure my environment is set up to debug tests.  However, I do get errors which have nothing to do with my test.

I am simply trying to run Jest with Angular 6 in VSCode and debug both my application and the tests.

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

environment.spec.ts

```
import { environment } from './environment';
describe('Production environment', () => {
    it('should have the environment not set for production', () => {
        expect(environment.production).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
    production: true
};
```

environment.prod.spec.ts

```
import { environment } from './environment.prod';
describe('Production environment', () => {
    it('should have the environment set for production', () => {
        expect(environment.production).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Error I receive:

```
FAIL  src/environments/environment.prod.spec.ts  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
      at patchXHR (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2926:39)
      at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2919:5
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.__load_patch (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:84:33)
      at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2917:6
      at Object.<anonymous>.FUNCTION (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:9:65)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:12:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setupJest.js:5:1)
```

setup-Jest.ts

```
/**
 * Jest setup file for automated testing
 */
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import './jestGlobalMocks';
```

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Jest All",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Jest Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
            "args": [
            "${relativeFile}"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
    ]
}
```

This appears to happen simply from importing the basic code needed to get Jest to run.  However, this does run in the bash environment without an error.

Answer (score 4):

I was troubleshooting this.  For me, in jest.config.js, setting testEnvironment to jsdom instead of node fixes the problem.

Comment: Test environment jest-environment-jsdom cannot be found. Make sure the testEnvironment configuration option points to an existing node module.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration


As of Jest 28 "jest-environment-jsdom" is no longer shipped by default, make sure to install it separately.